# Calls to CouchDB's _session always return 200

Tags: authentication, cookies, couchdb

Is it right that calls to the CouchDB `_session` endpoint always seem to return a `200` HTTP status code, even if the cookie I'm passing is absent or wrong?

Passing a wrong cookie or no cookie in my `GET` request headers always seems to return:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "userCtx": {
    "name": null,
    "roles": []
  },
  "info": {
    "authentication_db": "_users",
    "authentication_handlers": [
      "cookie",
      "default"
    ]
  }
}
```

When passing the correct cookie, I receive a slightly different response:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "userCtx": {
    "name": "jack",
    "roles": []
  },
  "info": {
    "authentication_db": "_users",
    "authentication_handlers": [
      "cookie",
      "default"
    ],
    "authenticated": "cookie"
  }
}
```

Is this standard behaviour? If it is, which key should I rely on to assume a successful authentication? Should it be `res.userCtx.name` or `res.info.authenticated`?

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/server/authn.html#get--_session) yet?

Comment: @DominicBarnes Cheers. I did see that page but for some reason I must have skipped past the `GET /session` part.

Comment: The documentation doesn't suggest that a 401 get returned for a bad cookie or no cookie at all, but it also doesn't suggest that it always return a 200 or the reasoning as to why.  I can't think of a single reason why anyone would need that endpoint to always return a userCtx object even when the session is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be standard behavior, although it's not explicitly stated in the documentation.

However, you can tell CouchDB to return a 401 response by setting `basic=true` in the query like this: `/_session?basic=true`.

It seems to suggest that it's useful for basic authentication, but it also works with a cookie authenticated user. (tested with CouchDB 2.0.0)

Comment: It's probably worth adding that, even with the added query, the `DELETE /_session` endpoint always seems to return `200 OK`. Even when passed an incorrect cookie. Strange.